# vb.net The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

when i run the cod i see these error 
The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.
on "adb.Fill(ds1)"

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Module ComModule
Public sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Public Sub openconn()
    If sqlconn.State = 1 Then sqlconn.Close()
    Try
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MRSOFTWARE-PC;Initial Catalog=ComShop;Integrated Security=True"
        sqlconn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Not Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign)
        sqlconn.Close()
        End
    End Try
End Sub
Public Function LastNum(tablename, orderbyfield) As Integer
    LastNum = 0
    Dim str = "select * from " & tablename & "order by" & orderbyfield
    Dim adb As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds1 = New DataSet
    adb.Fill(ds1)
    Dim DT As DataTable
    DT = ds1.Tables(0)
    If DT.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        Dim i = DT.Rows.Count - 1
        LastNum = Val(DT.Rows(i).Item(0))
    End If
End Function
```

End Module

---

```
TextBox1.Text = Format(LastNum("Customer", "CustomerId") + 1, "c0")
```

Comment: _Dim adb As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("select * from " & tablename & " order by " & orderbyfield)_ But pay attention to your inputs. This is an open door to sql injection (and to the missing spaces)

Comment: You only put the select command in a string, you have to give it to the `SqlDataAdapter` somehow (constructor, .SelectCommand propertie, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

First, You have to use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection.

All you need is, A [`SQLCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) Object which has a valid sql query. Then you should pass that SQLCommand object as args to [`SQLAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor.

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
    Module ComModule
        Public sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Public Sub openconn()
            If sqlconn.State = 1 Then sqlconn.Close()
            Try
                sqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MRSOFTWARE-PC;Initial Catalog=ComShop;Integrated Security=True"
                sqlconn.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Not Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign)
                sqlconn.Close()
                End
            End Try
        End Sub
        Public Function LastNum(tablename, orderbyfield) As Integer
            LastNum = 0
            Dim str = "select * from @tablename order by @orderbyfield"
            Dim sqlCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(str , sqlCon)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@tablename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value=tablename
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@orderbyfield", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value=orderbyfield
            Dim adb As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
            Dim ds1 = New DataSet
            adb.Fill(ds1)
            Dim DT As DataTable
            DT = ds1.Tables(0)
            If DT.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                Dim i = DT.Rows.Count - 1
                LastNum = Val(DT.Rows(i).Item(0))
            End If
        End Function


    End Module
```

Comment: Not work show in c1 on textbox1  i want when i click on Button1 show c3 and when click agen show c4 ....etc